# entity framework 6 dbcontext sqlite

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-6

The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.Linq, Version=1.0.88.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following articles for the required files:

- [SQLite in WPF with Entity Framework 6](http://nullskull.com/a/10476742/sqlite-in-wpf-with-entity-framework-6.aspx)
- [System.Data.SQLite on
  Entity Framework 6](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/systemdatasqlite-on-entity-framework-6.html)